# What is the difference between ChromeOptions and DesiredCapabilities

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am confused, where should I use `ChromeOptions` and `DesiredCapabilities`?

Can anyone please explain this?

Comment: check this out: https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/23559/what-is-the-difference-between-desiredcapabilities-chromeoptions-and-when-to-u

Answer (score 4):

The `ChromeOptions` class was introduced in the latest/updated version of Selenium. It is helpful to make changes in the Chrome browser, whereas the `DesiredCapabilities` class is an old concept -its usage in Java is deprecated- to configure or make changes in the browser.

But we can use both the `DesiredCapabilities` and `ChromeOptions` classes via a merge method. Please find below the example code:

```
DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();   // instantiate DC Class
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();          // instantiate CO Class
options.merge(cap);                               // passing DC class object to CO Class
driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Answer (score 1):

Capabilities are options that you can use to customize and configure a ChromeDriver session.

The WebDriver language APIs provides ways to pass capabilities to ChromeDriver.

The exact mechanism differs by the language, but most languages use one or both of the following mechanisms:

1. Use the ChromeOptions class. This is supported by Java, Python, etc.
2. Use the DesiredCapabilities class. This is supported by Python,
   Ruby, etc. While it is also available in Java, its usage in Java is deprecated.

for detail read this [Link](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/capabilities)

Answer (score 0):

chromeOptions - is used in Selenium to customize the Chrome browser (majorly in Java)

**Example:**

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

desiredCapablities - was used earlier in Selenium using Java (now its deprecated and not being used. 
(now DesiredCapablities are used in Appium driver for Mobile Automation)